# Passing tuple to postgres command in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a tuple having values

```
x = (45,96,50,60,80,70)
```

which is dynamic and may user add more to it, that should be passed to postgres command in python.

```
self._cr.execute("SELECT * FROM hr_payslip where id IN x") --> here x is the tuple variable
```

So the required command show be like this:

```
self._cr.execute("SELECT * FROM hr_payslip where id IN (45,96,50,60,80,70)")
```

I have tried to convert tuple to string but the column (id) required `int` values.

My question is how to pass tuple value to postgres command to get the required result from it .

Comment: `self._cr.execute("SELECT * FROM hr_payslip where id IN {}".format(x))` should work

Comment: Thnak you so much .. it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Odoo and a quick Google Search provides very little by means of the ORM they use.

Something along the lines of the format method in python could be used; similar to how you substitute in strings.

So

```
"SELECT * FROM hr_payslip where id IN {}".format(x)
```